# How to change the interface key: value: string to [{ [key: string]: string }

Tags: string, typescript, interface, signature, keyof

I have interface

```
IUser {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  cityLocation: string;
}
```

the value will be

```
const user: IUser = {
  "name": "John";
  "surname": "Smith";
  "cityLocation": "LA";
}
```

I have adapter, they have method which receive

```
function adapter(columns: { [key: string]: string }) {...}
```

when I try to do:

```
adapter(user);
```

I have error:

```
Argument of type 'IUser' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.   Index signature is missing in type 'IUser'.
```

How can I fix it?

(funny, but when I dont use signature IUser for object user - adapter works...)

Hope for your help. Big Thx!

Comment: You could add the index signature or just use `type`  instead of `interface` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgqgZwgJygXigbwLACgpQB2AhgLYQBcUCwyAloQOYDceBCArsieVTfU1b4oAYzqgAMgHsRxYHSmE+tBizwBfPHgAmEEQBtiyaADMOhEfMVRi24mGAoAFCKn6OpQgiqYoAbQBrCBBlAUYAXVDVKHUASioANyk6bS1cVy9gKA4kZCp4XPQsNigAIh4IUqpSgCkpAAtCUoAaEtLObjJK6oBlUnF6lraxSRk5BSbqiQBBUo0023tHZCcclFi0oA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `Index signature is missing in type 'IUser'` so add it:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  cityLocation: string;
  [key: string]: string;  
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO1kG8CwAUMsiHALYQBcymYUoA5gNxEmYCuUZlNdDIFm2QJgYAJ4AZAPYI4YYNJB96TVsWQBtANYRxKgYwC6BtSSIBfIkRgcQCBUuRwAJnAAOkKAAoE0gDYc5CCYNLhauvq0qoIm0YbIFgCUeH4hARAAdP7SjL4BQSGaAEQ8EMVGSVaERGl0yBzYUDQYTcgAvHjCZTTFAFLSABYgxQA0wpzcFNTIxQDK5GKDY8KiEjJyjsqzkgCCxZbWhK4eXt6N0ElHQA)